# EmguCV VideoWriter creates huge save files?

Tags: c#, video-capture, emgucv, video-encoding, webcam-capture

With the following code I am recording and saving video from the webcam to the disk. But even a 3 second video saves with a file size of roughly 50 MB. I assume I am misusing the VideoWriter class. Any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

namespace EmguCV_Webcam
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        #region Private variables

        private Capture currentDevice;
        private VideoWriter videoWriter;
        private bool recording;
        private int videoWidth;
        private int videoHeight;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeVariables();
            AttachButtonMacros();
            StartVideoFeed();
        }


        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private void InitializeVariables()
        {
            currentDevice = new Capture(0);
            recording = false;
            videoWidth = currentDevice.Width;
            videoHeight = currentDevice.Height;            
        }

        private void StartVideoFeed()
        {
            currentDevice.Start();
            currentDevice.ImageGrabbed += CurrentDevice_ImageGrabbed;
        }

        private void AttachButtonMacros()
        {
            StartRecordingButton.Click += StartRecordingButton_Click;
            StopRecordingButton.Click += StopRecordingButton_Click;
        }

        private void CurrentDevice_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Mat m = new Mat();
            currentDevice.Retrieve(m);
            VideoPictureBox.Image = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Bitmap;
            if (recording && videoWriter != null)
            {
                videoWriter.Write(m);
            }
        }

        private void StartRecordingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recording = true;
            SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            dialog.DefaultExt = ".avi";
            dialog.AddExtension = true;
            dialog.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            DialogResult dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if(dialogResult != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return;
            }
            videoWriter = new VideoWriter(dialog.FileName, 30, new Size(videoWidth, videoHeight), true);
        }

        private void StopRecordingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recording = false;
            if(videoWriter != null)
            {
                videoWriter.Dispose();
            }           
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're writing uncompressed video. You'll need to choose a codec to bring that size down. Is this on Linux or Windows? The reason I ask is because the [docs state](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/8e6a89b8-b00d-2674-2fe0-22a62fd8f48d.htm) that the constructor that you use in your code should "open a codec selection dialog" on Windows but " will use the default codec" in Linux. Have you tried [this constructor](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/0b658427-7e09-1cc0-53cf-be1a40f98140.htm) instead?

Comment: Thanks, just tried this, however it causes even more issues now. First off, it crashes the program unless I configure Visual Studio for x86. When I use the constructor that prompts the user to select a Codec, I get the following choices: Cinepak Codec by Radius, Logitech Video (I420), Intel IYUV codec, Microsoft RLE, Microsoft Video 1, and Full Frames (uncompressed). Some, including the first, cause an error:

Comment: System.AccessViolationException occurred
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=Emgu.CV.World
  StackTrace:
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cveVideoWriterWrite(IntPtr writer, IntPtr image)
   at Emgu.CV.VideoWriter.Write(Mat frame)
   at EmguCV_Webcam.Form1.CurrentDevice_ImageGrabbed(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\yoga 710\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\EmguCV_Webcam\EmguCV_Webcam\Form1.cs:line 70
   at Emgu.CV.Capture.Grab()
   at Emgu.CV.Capture.Run()

Comment: The remaining codecs either save the video to an unplayable state, or do not compress the video at all. There's got to be a way to compress videos without crashing...

Comment: I'd suggest looking into what FFMPEG can bring to the mix.

Answer (score 2):

You should use  compression. Try this

```
VideoWriter.Fourcc('M', 'P', '4', 'V')
```

So change

```
videoWriter = new VideoWriter(dialog.FileName, 30, new Size(videoWidth, videoHeight), true);
```

with

```
videoWriter = new VideoWriter(dialog.FileName, VideoWriter.Fourcc('M', 'P', '4', 'V'), 30, new Size(videoWidth, videoHeight), true);
```